# How to get Typing value used webview

Tags: android, webview

I want to get a key value while typing used webview in Android. I used webview.but how to get result? Can anybody help me? Thanks.

Comment: add some code and show us what you have done

Comment: Always good to add an example of what you have done, will help you to get answers

Answer (score 0):

I used some jQuery to get this handled. Here is a sample of the code I
started with.

http://jsfiddle.net/danconde/kGBw6/

Comment: Thank you ravi .It's is possible to get android.

Comment: My please!! but whenever you find anything useful please click on "You find it useful"

Comment: i want to get character ravi.

Comment: Showing characters while typing in android? ravi